# java reverse triangle star pattern

Tags: java

It is easy to print using for loop but I want to print it using while loop but I am unable to do so and also can't see any mistake in this:

```
int i, j;
i = 1;
j = 5;

while (i<=5){
    while (j>=i){
        System.out.print("*");
        j--;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    i++;
}
```

[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag4Mt.jpg)

Comment: You need to reset the value of `j` in the outer loop.

Comment: I have tried it but it becoming an infinite loop

Comment: "It is easy to print using for loop" in such case use fact that `for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){action}` is equivalent of `{int i = 0; while(i<MAX){action; i++} }` and try again.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reset the value of `j` in the outer loop i.e.

```
int i, j;
i = 1;

while (i<=5){
    j = 5;
    while (j>=i){
        System.out.print("*");
        j--;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by [@Turamarth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457643/turamarth), you should reset the value of j in the outer loop:

```
final int size = 5; 
int linesPrinted = 0;
int remaining = size;

while (linesPrinted<size){
    while (remaining>linesPrinted){
        System.out.print("*");
        remaining--;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    linesPrinted++;
    remaining=size;
}
```